# What ways exist to earn PDUs to keep active all PMI Certifications?

Tags: career, pmp, pmi-framework, pdu

Lets use this question to list all possible ways to earn PDUs.  Please moderator covert this question in a community post.

Summary of all the answers:

- PMI Chapter regular meetings (2 PDUs per meeting)
- [Six Sigma Green Belt](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/175/what-ways-exist-to-earn-pdus-to-keep-active-all-pmi-certifications/185#185) certification (25 PDUs, cost about $250)
- Write an article or paper
- Take a PMI quiz
- Volunteer
- Take a class
- Attend a seminar
- Self education
- Give a presentation

[Complete List from the PMI Organization](http://www.pmi.org/Certification/Twelve-Ways-to-Earn-PDUs.aspx)

I will pick as the right answer the one that get's the most votes.

Comment: PMI's handbook contains a list of pretty much all the ways to earn PDUs, by category...

Comment: SSGB will give you **exactly** 25PDU :)

Comment: Related - http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/1871/34

Comment: Do you know that you can watch a movie and add 4 PDU for that? Starnge but true. Of course, you need to be precise what you have learned from that movie.

Answer (score 5):

- write an article or paper
- take a PMI quiz
- volunteer
- take a class
- attend a seminar
- self education
- give a presentation
- Look [here](http://www.pmi.org/Certification/Twelve-Ways-to-Earn-PDUs.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Some employers are certified training providers with PMI.  If they are, you can often take internal training classes at work and register them for PDUs.

Comment: Hi SchwartzE, Do you know if PMI will have to list them in their forum for the employer to give give the PDUs?  I am just curios how to find out?

Comment: Our company's training program registers and has a code to enter into the PMI site to register the PDUs.  I'm guessing if you contact PMI and give them your employer, they can look it up.

Answer (score 2):

**Participate on this site.** You can claim PDUs under Category C (self-directed learning); I myself claimed around 4-5 PDUs already from spending time on this site. (You can use RescueTime to track how long you're here.)

More details are listed [on my blog post about this topic](http://ashiqalibhai.com/easy-free-self-paced-pdus-yes-really/).

Answer (score 1):

[Six Sigma Green Belt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma) certification will give you 25 PDUs. It costs around $250 and can be passed online.

Answer (score 1):

Simply being a PM earns you PDU's.  I believe it is 5 PDU's per year.